Why won't the permission_handler request permssion for Video on Android SDK 34?
I am using the permission_handler package for my flutter app and with a Pixel 8 Pro API 35 emulator, I am trying to request access to device gallery. This is the error i get when trying to request permission to android videos:
await Permission.videos.request();

flutter:
D/permissions_handler(22246): No permissions found in manifest for: []32

According to the packages documentation on pub.dev, under the FAQ, requesting 'storage' permissions always returns 'denied' on Android 13+. And so the solution would be to use Permission.photos and Permission.videos.
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are deprecated so now use READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO.
I have also tried the docs specified compileSdk as 33, but the build finds 17 issues with CheckAarMetadataWorkAction checking the AAR metadata. So i am using 34 for my compileSdk.
So Permissions.photos and Permissions.audio works as intended, except for Permissions.videos
AndroidManifext.xml
<manifest>
    ...

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/> 

    <!-- I added these even though they are deprecated -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 
</manifest>

android/app/src/build.gradle
android {
    ...
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }
}


Umm.. I suggests to try this.
<manifest ...>
  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"
    tools:targetApi="eclair" />

  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_USER_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" />
  
  ...

</manifest>

Maybe It cause Android OS external policy. Android assigns select external storage's things to user.
